# Add image to a placeholder of word template

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, office-interop

Hi all I have code that is having Open XML SDK to find MERGEFIELDs in Microsoft Word documents and replace them with the provided data, this is working well but **I want to replace provided string with the image now**.

Code from the link:

> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38575/Fill-Mergefields-in-docx-Documents-without-Microso

```
    using (WordprocessingDocument docx = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
                    {
                        //  2010/08/01: addition
                        ConvertFieldCodes(docx.MainDocumentPart.Document);

                        // first: process all tables
                        foreach (var field in docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<SimpleField>())
                        {
                            string fieldname = GetFieldName(field, out switches);
                           // I will get fieldname "ImgLogo" and then I want to add an Image at this position. 
                        }
                    }
```

**I will get fieldname "ImgLogo" as shown above and then I want to add an Image at this position. Full code is shown in the above link.**

Help me here Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mergefield if statements. Write your statement out and after you've finished paste the image into the else segment of the if statement.

https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MailMerge/MMergeIfFields.htm

Press Alt + F9 to show mergefield codes in word / excel. If should edit the template document and not the end product. As you can't see the fields after they've been merged.

When you merge in your picture it'll overwrite both { MERGEFIELD MergeImage } fields. When it's overwrites them, the { MERGEFIELD MergeImage } = "" will not be true and will show your image instead of the placeholder. As stated, the placeholder image should be pasted into the = "Paste Placeholder here".

This works as before you merge your image, { MERGEFIELD MergeImage } is equal to a blank string.

E.g.

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD MergeImage } = "" "Paste Placeholder here" "{ MERGEFIELD MergeImage }" }
```

break down of the above:

```
{ IF CONDITION "TRUE" "FALSE" }
```

If nothing has been merged in you'll get the place holder, otherwise you'll get the merged image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am working in c# and the word template has <<Img_String>> this placeholder. So how can I achieve to input an image(by replacing the placeholder) technically in the document and then save it. Please reply with context to the above-provided link in question.

Comment: When you do the merge from in C# it overwrites the mergefields. So you just make the changes to the word document in question. Press Alt + F9 to see mergefields instead the grey boxes.

Comment: Remember to press Alt + F9 after you've finished to return to normal... I've been very confused before when I was still in the mode which displays the full mergefield in word

Comment: Thanks for the reply I don't want change in the document, in the document it is an <<Imglogo>> now when I get the field in the code and then I want to past image in document and then save it.